# iOS App Today Extension not uploaded to physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8-today-widget, ios-extensions

I am creating a today widget for my app http://budgt.ch as some users have requested quick access to key functionality.

The (preliminary) extension is working fine on iOS simulators, installed like this:

1) install latest container app
2) install extension with 'today' as container

However: i cannot seem to get the extension to show on a physical device (i am currently testing with an iPhone 6).

- xcode says: Build successfull
- Extension is not showing up in today view

any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the deployment target for the extension is less than or equal to the system version of the device? Also, try rebooting the device.

Comment: I recall a number of "clean, fail to attach, clean, run" iterations when working with a today extension.  Also make sure you [set the host app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SettingExtensionHost.html) as Today.

Comment: thank you @EricS, it's always the small stupid mistakes ;) had a 'too high' deployment on the extension :) you can put it into an answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046255/198927

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that the deployment target for the extension is less than or equal to the system version of the device?